Camera not working
The camera not working in Ubuntu 24.04.


Could you please include more details in your question? Which camera do you have, how is it connected etc.

Same problem. I installed cheese and is working but not with new default app. My camara is a Red dragon hitman 1080

Steps to solve this issue: (It works for me and should work for you also)
1) Open the Terminal CTRL + Alt + T
2) Update the package lists from the repositories
~ sudo apt update

3) Restart pipewire
~ systemctl --user restart pipewire

4) Run snapshot from terminal. The package name of this camera app is snapshot
~ snapshot

It should work from now on.

This works for me to get the web camera app to work, but doesn't seem to fix my webcam not being found in other apps.

@MarlenT.B. Yeah! This is only a temporary solution.  I think there is some issue with camera driver also. UBUNTU NEEDS TO FIX THIS WITH AN UPDATE. If you restart your PC again, you have to type these commands again to start the camera. In my laptop, my other apps are accessing my camera with no issues. Are you using Desktop with separate camera?

This really works. I'm a little perplexed about step 2. What does updating the package index has to do with pipewire or snapshot here when we don't install anything?

Btw. this also fixes my problem with the Decoder flatpak. This application had this issue already in 23.10, even though I gave it permission to use the webcam in Flatseal. Thanks!

@Green绿色 You can ignore this step but it is best practice to update package index so that we can work on latest version. In case any related package got any major updates it can conflict. Remember that, initially the problem was started from updating to Ubuntu 24.04.

@Md.MusfiqurRahaman Yes, as I understand it, the apt update is a no-op in this context, as long as we don't do apt install or apt upgrade. Sure, it's best to update the package index every time when installing or upgrading, but for anything else, it should be pretty unrelated.

snapshot does not seem to exist anymore?

Given the outrage about required repetition upon restart, I did the following:
Open the app menu on Ubuntu, search for "Startup Applications", open it, click "add", give it a meaningful name, e.g "Camera workaround" in the command type the systemctl --user restart pipewire and in the comment write something elaborative, e.g: Workaround + link to this very article.
And voila, the camera works upon every boot. As a drawback: this solution might increase boot time.

I have the same problem , camera app probably not installed , go to app center you see that not installed , if you install the app it  works but there will be 2 camera apps in app center

I fixed this by installing a package for media devices:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install v4l-utils

Then check if the camera is detected:
v4l2-ctl --list-devices

Finally, open the Ubuntu camera:
snapshot


If the "Camera" app doesn't work for you...
Add yourself to the "video" group and it'll work fine.
sudo adduser $USER video
Then you MUST log out, then use this command to check if you're in the video group:
groups
If you don't show up there, then you MUST reboot.

sudo adduser $USER video
This worked for me

You can install cheese instead of using snapshot:
sudo apt install cheese

Dell laptops with MIPI webcams (like Latitude, Precision, XPS) do not work on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. The problem? Ubuntu 24.04 doesn’t currently support MIPI webcams, nor has the drivers ready befre shipping the new version :) Dell and Canonical are working on it, but no fix yet.
Dell confirmed this problem for the following models:



Latitude
XPS
Precision




7340
9315
5470


7440
9320
5480


9430
9340
5490


7640

5680




5690



FIX ?
For now, if your camera is important, it's best to stay on Ubuntu 22.04 since the issue only happens after the upgrade.
Here’s the link to the Dell article: https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000201043/mipi-webcam-does-not-work-on-ubuntu-24-04-lts

Any news here? I have a 9340 and bought it since I needed hardware that fully works with Linux and it is sad that webcam is not working. I tried 24.04 and 24.10 now but no success or not sure if I need to do something very specific to make it work. 22.04.5 I tried and also did not work (and it is too old).

Btw this is also happening in my HP Laptop.

I'd like to add that the problem occurs on:
OS: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS x86_64 
Host: Inspiron 16 5630 
Kernel: 6.8.0-51-generic
And yet the camera works just fine in web apps (e.g google meet).
